# Serial Port Counting Meter clicks away when XP Embedded Starts Up

Tags: windows, windows-xp, embedded, serial-port

We have a counting meter hooked up to the serial port of a PC running Windows XP Embedded and everytime Windows starts, the meter starts clicking away about 90 times. We have tried using /fastdetect in boot.ini and it didn't work, even though it did work on XP Pro. We tried adding SkipEnumeration to the Device Parameter in the registry and it didn't work. When Plug&Play is disabled it won't click, but this isn't an option for us. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: figured it out... for anyone interested having this problem... I edited the Plug&Play registry and added a DependOnService multi-string with "Spooler" service as the data... this makes Plug&Play start later and allows enough time so that the meter isn't clicking like crazy

Answer (score 1):

for anyone interested having this problem... I edited the Plug&Play registry and added a DependOnService multi-string with "Spooler" service as the data... this makes Plug&Play start later and allows enough time so that the meter isn't clicking crazy